# how to thin out adobe CS 5.5

Tags: macos, adobe

I wan't to get rid of unnecessary files on my SSD HD. 
Although I only checked Illustrator, InDesign, Acrobat and Photoshop (and something iOs-related) while installing, Adobe has still installed a bunch of other folders/applications.
Which of the following folders can I safely delete?

1. Adobe
2. Adobe After Effects CS5.5
3. Adobe Bridge CS5.1
4. Adobe Device Central CS5.5
5. Adobe Extension Manager CS5.5
6. Adobe Flash Builder 4.5
7. Adobe Flash CS5.5
8. Adobe Media Encoder CS5.5
9. Adobe OnLocation CS5.1

Comment: Practically, I've not had good luck taking away parts that the system things is installed when update time arrives. Are you open to uninstalling everything and re-running the installer to just install the pieces you feel you need?

Comment: I only chose to install Illustrator, InDesign, Acrobat and Photoshop (and something iOs-related). Those other folders are automatically installed as well. I don't want to mess things up, i just want to know whether I can safely delete parts, and which.

Comment: Those would be great details to edit into the question. Perhaps the installer isn't clear about how to selectively install parts of the suite.

Answer (score 2):

You could follow the instructions on [this page at Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/uninstall-creative-suite-cs5-cs5.html#main_Uninstall_Creative_Suite_5_or_CS5_5__Mac_OS_) and uninstall the CS5 packages you don't need.

If you want to get rid of *even more* useless space, you could try [Monolingual](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/7758/monolingual), which removes unneeded language resources.

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried Adobes uninstaller, and it leaves things unclear.
It only shows me the applications I intentionally installed. It doesn't give me an option to get rid of applications like Bridge and so on. (there's almost 2Gb of folders I don't know why to keep)

Monolingual was a great tip, it saved me 1,8 Gb!